# AWS Load Balancer DNS is working but it doesn't pass the health check

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a the application load balancer set up with a security group. I also have my ec2 instance (windows) set up with another security group. My ec2 instance is configured in vpc.

If I type the load balancer dns (for example http://alb-myrpoject-437610392.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/) on the browser it works but the health check fails. Here is the screenshot of the target group:

[image]

[image]

I am using the Apache web server.

Any idea why the health check is failing while the load balancer dns works?

Comment: Is the web page correctly shown in the browser?

Comment: yes, the web page is correctly shown in the browser.

Comment: 400 means health check is not able to find the webpage on the root of your EC2. What happens if you try `http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_EC2`? Do you see a webpage? If not, specify the correct path in Path setting of your health check.

Comment: http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_EC2 doesn't work in my browser. What do you mean specifying the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying to help with your comments. I realized that I didn't give enough info. Okay, I've finally figured it out. On the security group of the ec2 instance, I also added

```
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0
```

[image]

Now the health check became healthy I can also reach out my web page using my ip of my ec2 instance.

Comment: You only need to add alb security group on port 80 in your EC2 security group. Everything else in your picture is you asking for trouble. don't do that.

Comment: You mean I should remove the last two?

Comment: Remove first and last two.

Comment: I just did. Yes, I still get healthy check status. But now I can't connect using my ip in my browser. I can connect only with my load balancer dns (alb-myproject...) I guess that's how it is supposed to be. Right?

Comment: Correct. That’s how it is supposed to be.

Comment: But now I no longer can connect to my ec2 instance remotely using the rdp connection. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I had to put the rdp back to be able to connect to the server. The health check shows healthy. A relevant quick question: to make the load balancer dns work for accessing in my browser, I had to turn off the public firewall in my windows server. Is that something normal? Or is there any way to access it while keeping the firewall on?